# customer_save_after and customer_register_success event in custom observer customer session is blank in mycustom fuction?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer-account, customer-session

This is my observer function for customer_register_success and **customer_save_after**  **event it execute my custom url but i m getting blank session**

```
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

```
public function doSomething($observer)
{    
 $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();
  $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

      $session=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
   $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->getCompurl().'state_new/1');
    if (!$Customer->getCustomerActivated()) {
    }
    else{
       //$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($Customer);
       $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args



        $dataarray = Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->getData_array();
        $sampleid=$dataarray['sampleid'];

        $state=$dataarray['state'];
        if($state==1)
        {
          $collection=Mage::getSingleton('mymodule/mymodule')->customisesaved($sampleid);
        if($collection)
        {
            $url=Mage::getUrl('mymodule/mymodule/customshow');
             Mage::log($url,null,"url.log");            
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
             Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
             exit;
        }          

    }

}
}
```

Suggest me some solution.print_r($url) $url  has my custom controller url but not executing it.This is **my custom controller where i want to redirect and continue the process**

```
public function customaddAction()
    {
     $sampleid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('sampleid');

    $login_new=$this->getRequest()->getparam('state_new');
        Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->setData('data_array',array('sampleid'=>$sampleid,'state'=>1));
            if((!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())||(!$login_new))
        {
        Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->setData('data_array',array('sampleid'=>$sampleid,'state'=>1));
           Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->setData('compurl',Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
            $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');

        }
     if((Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())||($login_new==1))
        {
        Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->setData('data_array',array('sampleid'=>$sampleid,'state'=>0));
         $sampleid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('sampleid');

          $collection=Mage::getSingleton('mymodule/mymodule')->customisesaved($sampleid);
        if($collection)
        {
        $this->_redirect('mymodule/mymodule/customshow');
        }
        else{
                 $this->_redirectReferer();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want redirect to `customshow` or `customadd` action?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    exit;
```

Comment: thanks for answer it doesn't redirect or do anything but when i do inspect element it shows my custom url but the user is not loggedin and give Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .ytmpa-

Comment: I have doubt on this line    $url = Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->getCompurl().'state_new=1' please print this url in log for check your Url by using: Mage::log($url,null,"url.log")

Comment: please see my updated question.I have included the controller function that i am calling from the $url

Comment: Why you need to redirect it on your controller? when you can do the same thing in your observer

Comment: please see my updated question i am executing my code inside observer but it does not execute it